# Doesn't display file content in the Console

Tags: java, swing, java.util.scanner

This program that I adapted from one of the Java books I have won't display the selected file from the file chooser in the console:

```
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
   JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
   if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) 
           == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {              

   // Get the selected File
   java.io.File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

   // Create new scanner file.
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 

   // 
           while (in.hasNext()) {
               System.out.println(in.nextLine());
               System.out.println("Hello");
            }
   // Close file
           in.close();
        }

       else {
       System.out.println("No File Selected.");
   }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesnt compile - youre missing a class declaration

Comment: Why are you using a rich client file chooser yet sending output to the console?  Since `JTextComponent` has a [`read(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29) method, it would be simpler and more robust to keep it all 'rich client'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the selected file as the `Scanner` source rather than the system `InputStream`

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't working because you are not using the file obtained from the JFileChooser. Try changing:

```
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

To

```
   Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
```

Comment: Thank you!
Is that because the scanner class is shifted only for the file, and not input on the keyboard?

Comment: When you write new `Scanner(System.in)` you are passing `Scanner` an `InputStream` which is located in the `System` class. However in your example that's not what you wanted to use it for, so you needed to pass it the right object, which, in this case, was the `File` object you just obtained from `JFileChooser`. I hope that makes sense, feel free to ask for clarification if anything doesn't make sense.